# Jenkins - Commit an update in the PR build

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins job for my puppet stuff and really all those jobs do are validation and deployment to puppet. The question I have is that as part of that build I'd like to force an update via `bundle` which will update the `puppetfile` which needs to then be checked in as part of that PR.

One of the concerns I have is that the commit to the PR will end up triggering another build, which will trigger another update... so on and so forth.

The only thing I was able to find in regards to this was that you can control to some extent how the jobs run (restart/stop and new from new commits) but those seem to be blanket settings and not specific to the job instance and no way that I could find via the pipeline stuff to control that.

I have to imagine this is something that people do and that there is a method to this but my google foo is failing or I'm searching on the wrong terms.

Also, if it matters we're using github enterprise onsite.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: There might be a better way than what I am about to describe (it seems heavy handed) but we also found the built-in Jenkins exclusion settings insufficient. Primarily because it only applied to triggered builds not scheduled Multi-branch pipeline scans. Also this only applies to *Pipeline* Groovy DSL jobs; not to freestyle jobs or declarative Pipeline jobs.

**Summary**

Best explained in pseudocode

```
if git changed files since last run == 0 then
  no need to change puppetfile
  end build
endif

if 1 file changed and it is puppetfile then
  if the contents of the change is just the auto-changed puppetfile stuff
    no need to change puppetfile again
    end build
  endif
endif

if we get here then more stuff changed so do the auto-change puppetfile stuff
```

**Details**

For a concrete implementation I will use a Javascript project's `package.json` as an example but it's exactly the same situation as the `puppetfile`. Just replace `package.json` with `puppetfile` and `version:` with whatever content change you auto-generate that should not trigger another build.

First we need some utility methods:

```
/**
 * Utility method to run git and handle splitting its output
 */
def git( command ) {
  def output = []
  outputRaw = sh(
    script: "git $command",
    returnStdout: true
  )
  if ( !outputRaw.empty ) {
    output = outputRaw.split('\n')
  }
  return output
}

/**
 * The names of files changed since the last successful build
 */
def getFilesChangedSinceLastSuccessfulBuild() {
  def filesChanged = []
  if (lastSuccessfulCommit) {
    filesChanged = git "diff --name-only $currentCommit '^$lastSuccessfulCommit'"
  }
  echo "DEBUG: Files changed $filesChanged (size ${filesChanged.size()})"
  return filesChanged
}

/**
 * Get changes as a list without context
 */
def getContextFreeChanges() {
  def contentsChanged = []
  if (lastSuccessfulCommit) {
    contentsChanged = git "diff --unified=0 $lastSuccessfulCommit $currentCommit | egrep '^\\+ ' || exit 0"
  }
  echo "DEBUG: Contents changed: $contentsChanged (size ${contentsChanged.size()})"
  return contentsChanged

}
```

Then we take those and create `needToBumpVersion()` (rename as appropriate) which ties it all together to figure out of any auto-generate changes need to happen:

```
/**
 * Do we need to actually increment version in package.json
 */
def needToBumpVersion() {
  def filesChanged = getFilesChangedSinceLastSuccessfulBuild()
  if (filesChanged.size() == 0) {
    echo "INFO: No files changed, no need to bump version"
    return false
  }
  if (filesChanged.size() == 1 && filesChanged[0] == 'package.json') {
    def contentsChanged = getContextFreeChanges()
    if (contentsChanged.size() == 1 && contentsChanged[0] =~ /"version":/) {
      echo "INFO: Don't need to bump version, it has already been done"
      return false
    }
  }
  echo "INFO: We do need to bump the version, more than just package.json version string changed"
  return true
}
```

and *finally* you can then use this method to figure out whether to make the auto-generated changes and commit them:

```
if (needToBumpVersion()) {
  // Do bump here
}
```

Comment: awesome! going to play around with this, see what i can get working.